# Sphinx gives warning as it cannot find imported file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-sphinx, autodoc

I am trying to generate docs but am running into a warning in the command line. I've been searching the site and can't find a working solution for me. I narrowed the cause down to the import in ClassB.

My folder structure is:

[image: folder structure]

The `__init__.py` files have no content.

classA.rst:

```
classA
======

.. automodule:: app.ClassA
    :members:
```

classB.rst:

```
classB
======

.. automodule:: app.ClassB
    :members:
```

index.rst (toctree only):

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:

   classA
   classB
```

conf.py (path only):

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../src'))
```

ClassA.py:

```
class A:
    def sayNo(self):
        print('NO!')
```

ClassB.py:

```
from ClassA import A

class B:
    def sayNoB(self):
        no = A()
        no.sayNo()
```

The warning from the command line:

```
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'ClassB' from module 'app'; the following exception was raised:
No module named 'ClassA'
```

Comment: maybe you should use relative import - with dot - like `from .ClassA import A`

Comment: @furas could you add that as an asnwer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for me you should use relative import - with `dot`

```
from .ClassA import A
```